# VBA: Find the average of a column with a dynamic range

Tags: vba, dynamic, range, formula, average

I have data in the range P14:P28. I wrote a macro that appends a new data point at P14 every time the macro is used, which increases the range of the column to P14:P29, and also calculates the average of the new range (P14:P29) in cell P31. The problem is that I need the formula to be dynamic, so that when another data point is appended to the table, the average of the newest range (P14:P30) is calculated in cell P32. When the macro is used again, another data point is added, the average is calculated over the range P14:P31 in cell P33, and so on and so forth.

Thanks for the help in advance,

Comment: show your code, please

Comment: Is the row below the average blank?

Comment: Here is the code for the average:

Comment: Cells(31, 16) = (Cells(14, 16) + Cells(15, 16) + Cells(16, 16) + Cells(17, 16) + Cells(18, 16) + Cells(19, 16) + Cells(20, 16) + Cells(21, 16) + Cells(22, 16) + Cells(23, 16) + Cells(24, 16) + Cells(25, 16) + Cells(26, 16) + Cells(27, 16) + Cells(28, 16) + Cells(29, 16)) / 16

Comment: The problem is that i have to update the average formula and where it is located every time I append a data point to the column.

Comment: Yes Peter, the row below the cell where the average is calculated is blank.

Comment: @user3242245 will the row with the Average be the lowest row in the form, or just the lowest row in that column?

Comment: @AlexD, I'm not sure what you mean exactly by 'lowest row in the form,' but row 38 has a title in B38 describing a set of data in the range B42:P58. The row with the Average is not the lowest row in the worksheet. It is the lowest row in that column until the next range of the aforementioned data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
Sub AveragePercentChangeAllSheets()
'Finds the average of a column P with a dynamic range for all the worksheets
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
Sheets(i).Select

iRow = 14
Cell_val = Cells(iRow, 16)
While Cell_val <> ""
iRow = iRow + 1
Cell_val = Cells(iRow, 16)
Wend
Cells(iRow + 1, 16) = "=AVERAGE(P14:P" & iRow - 1 & ")"

Next i
End Sub
```